# Let $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ where $\mathbb Z$ is the set of integers and $f(x) = x^5 + 101$. Is a one-to-one function? Why or why not.

Tags: functions

1. Let  $f: \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers and $f(x) = x^5 + 101$.  Is it  a one-to-one function?  Please explain why or why not.

Comment: Can you find $x\in\Bbb Z$ such that $f(x)=0$?

Answer (score 2):

The definition of one-to-one means that if $f(x) = f(y)$ then $x=y$.  We just need to check this:  $$f(x) = x^5 + 101 = y^5 +101 =f(y) \implies x^5 = y^5 \implies x=y$$
So, $f$ is one-to-one.  A geometric way of viewing this is using the vertical line test for continuous functions.  If you draw a vertical line anywhere in the graph of the function and only one unique point is hit, the function is one-to-one.

Comment: Thanks for the response to my question. If Z: set of integers is defined as Z:{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3} , how can we plot a graph for f(x) = x^5 + 101 ?

Comment: If the $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is one to one, check that, in this case, it will actually imply $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is one to one.  In short, you can just graph the function normally (and take a moment to understand why this is true).